# How, I can use select with max,min function in (linq and lambda)?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, asp.net-web-api2

I need search max and min value using linq and lambda. I have sql select, for example:

```
SELECT 
      [ProdID]
      ,min([APY]) as minAPY
      ,max([APY]) as minAPY
  FROM [dbase].[dbo].[Dept]
  group by ProdID
  order by ProdID
```

Thanks for help me!

Comment: did u tried anything??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query should be something like:

```
var res = from x in db.Debt
          group x by x.ProdID into y
          orderby y.Key
          select new 
          { 
              ProdID = y.Key, 
              minAPY = y.Min(z => z.APY), 
              maxAPY = y.Max(z => z.APY) 
          };
```

As you can see, it reflects quite nicely with the TSQL query. The only "important" thing is the `into y` after the `group` (necessary to continue the query)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = from table in ContextDB.Dept 
                   group table by table.ProdID into tableGroup
                   order by table.ProdId
                   select new 
                   {
                        ProdID = tableGroup.Key, 
                        minAPY = tableGroup.Min(item => item.APY), 
                        maxAPY = tableGroup.Max(item => item.APY) 
                   }
```